# how to parse XML using XmlReader along with their closing tags?

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, xmlreader

Consider the following XML which I have to parse.

```
<root>
  <item>
    <itemId>001</itemId>
    <itemName>test 1</itemName>
    <description/>
  </item>
</root>
```

I have to parse each of its tag and store it into a table as follows:

```
TAG_NAME        TAG_VALUE         IsContainer
------------    --------------    -----------
root            null              true
item            null              true
itemId          001               false
itemName        test 1            false
description     null              false
/item           null              true
/root           null              true
```

Now to get this done, I am using `XmlReader` as this allows us to parse each & every node.

I am doing it as follows:

I created the following class to contain each tag's data

```
public class XmlTag
{
  public string XML_TAG { get; set; }      
  public string XML_VALUE { get; set; }      
  public bool IsContainer { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to get the list of tags(including closing ones) as follows:

```
    private static List<XmlTag> ParseXml(string path)
    {
        var tags = new List<XmlTag>();

        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(path))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var tag = new XmlTag();
                bool shouldAdd = false;
                switch (reader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        shouldAdd = true;
                        tag.XML_TAG = reader.Name;

                        //How do I get the VALUE of current reader?
                        //How do I determine if the current node contains children nodes to set IsContainer property of XmlTag object?
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                        shouldAdd = true;
                        tag.XML_TAG = string.Format("/{0}", reader.Name);
                        tag.XML_VALUE = null;
                        //How do I determine if the current closing node belongs to a node which had children.. like ROOT or ITEM in above example?
                        break;
                }

                if(shouldAdd)
                    tags.Add(tag);
            }
        }

        return tags;
    }
```

but I am having difficulty determining the following:

1. How to determine if current `ELEMENT` contains children XML nodes? To set `IsContainer` property.
2. How to get the value of current node value if it is of type `XmlNodeType.Element`

**Edit:**

I have tried to use LINQ to XML as follows:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"SampleItem.xml");

var tags = (from t in xdoc.Descendants()
            select new XmlTag
            {
                XML_TAG = t.Name.ToString(),
                ML_VALUE = t.HasElements ? null : t.Value,
                IsContainer = t.HasElements
            }).ToList();
```

This gives me the XML tags and their values but this does not give me ALL the tags including the closing ones. That's why I decided to try `XmlReader`. But If I have missed anything in LINQ to XML example, please correct me.

Comment: Do you *have* to use `XmlReader` in the first place? Unless you're worried about loading enormous files into memory, using LINQ to XML (or even just XmlDocument) will make life much simpler.

Comment: I dont have to use XmlReader and the files are not enormous at all. The only reason I tried XmlReader is because of the table structure. I have to read all the XML tags (including the closing ones). I would really appreciate if you could give me a small example of how can I use LINQ to XML or XmlDocument to do so. Thanks

Comment: @JonSkeet - Can you please elaborate or reffer some link for us why should we not use XmlReader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as noted by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855443/how-to-parse-xml-using-xmlreader-along-with-their-closing-tags/20855827#comment31285986_20855443) you should probably consider using other tools, like [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) possibly with [`LINQ to XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) (**EDIT**: an example with [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) follows).

Having said that, here is the simplest solution for what you have currently (note that it's not the cleanest possible code, and it doesn't have much validation):

```
private static List<XmlTag> ParseElement(XmlReader reader, XmlTag element)
{
    var result = new List<XmlTag>() { element };
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                element.IsContainer = true;
                var newTag = new XmlTag() { XML_TAG = reader.Name };
                if (reader.IsEmptyElement)
                {
                    result.Add(newTag);
                }
                else
                {
                    result.AddRange(ParseElement(reader, newTag));
                }
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                element.XML_VALUE = reader.Value;
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                if (reader.Name == element.XML_TAG)
                {
                    result.Add(new XmlTag()
                        {
                            XML_TAG = string.Format("/{0}", reader.Name),
                            IsContainer = element.IsContainer
                        });
                }

                return result;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

private static List<XmlTag> ParseXml(string path)
{
    var result = new List<XmlTag>();

    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(path))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            {
                result.AddRange(ParseElement(
                    reader,
                    new XmlTag() { XML_TAG = reader.Name }));
            }
            else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
            {
                result.Add(new XmlTag() 
                    { 
                        XML_TAG = string.Format("/{0}",current.Name)
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

An example using [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx). This will give slightly different result for self-enclosing tags (`<description/>` in your case). You can change this behaviour easily, depending on what you want.

```
private static IEnumerable<XmlTag> ProcessElement(XElement current)
{
    if (current.HasElements)
    {
        yield return new XmlTag() 
            { 
                XML_TAG = current.Name.ToString(),
                IsContainer = true
            };

        foreach (var tag in current
            .Elements()
            .SelectMany(e => ProcessElement(e)))
        {
            yield return tag;
        }

        yield return new XmlTag() 
            { 
                XML_TAG = string.Format("/{0}", current.Name.ToString()),
                IsContainer = true
            };
    }
    else
    {
        yield return new XmlTag()
            { 
                XML_TAG = current.Name.ToString(), 
                XML_VALUE = current.Value
            };

        yield return new XmlTag()
            {
                XML_TAG = string.Format("/{0}",current.Name.ToString())
            };
    }
}
```

And using it:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"test.xml");
var tags = ProcessElement(xdoc.Root).ToList();
```

Comment: I have updated your answer with some small modifications to match exactly what I needed. Sorry for not asking you in advance.

Comment: @Aamir It's ok, it's a right thing to do. I see that your edit was rejected by other people (you edited changing original meaning - formatting, and order of methods usually should stay original) - I'll try to incorporate some of your modifications into the post. Feel free to edit it again if you find something you can improve - I'll approve it if I will be around.